# Имитация вычислит. деятельности (Android)

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте!

Задача:
Приложение должно работать в фоновом режиме и выполнять какие-либо вычислительные операции (имитация работы или обмена данными между компонентами устройства). При этом можно было бы задавать период работы и простоя (период "импульсов" и их длительность).

Как можно реализовать эту имитацию деятельности?

Добавлено: Эти самые периоды должны задаваться через конфигурационный файл. Например, "первое число" - период следования "импульсов" (по сути - время простоя), "следующие числа" - длительность работы (т.е. длительность "импульса").

Цель: измерить ЭМИ (эл.-маг. излучение) во время работы этого фонового приложения.

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: как то так Thread.sleep(1000); остановит поток, в котором будет вызван, на 1 секунду

Comment: Ты можешь сделать такую имитацию используя AsyncTask. Это позволит тебе не дать зависнуть UI + ты сможешь показывать прогресс обновляя UI.